# Extend Javac parser behavior

Tags: java, plugins, javac, java-9, annotation-processing

I have a Javac Plug-in (implementation of `com.sun.source.util.Plugin`) and I want it to alter parser behavior.

I can extend `com.sun.tools.javac.parser.ParserFactory` and register it in my `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context` when my plug-in is initialized, but there is a problem:
Plugins are initialized right after initialization of `JavacProcessingEnvironment` which creates all things necessary for compilation including `ParserFactory`, but I can only add my `ParserFactory` to context, not overwrite existing one.

Here is a piece of code I am interested in (`com.sun.tools.javac.api.BasicJavacTask`):

```
public void initPlugins(Set<List<String>> pluginOpts) {
    PlatformDescription platformProvider = context.get(PlatformDescription.class);

    if (platformProvider != null) {
        for (PluginInfo<Plugin> pluginDesc : platformProvider.getPlugins()) {
            //Init platform plugins
        }
    }

    if (pluginOpts.isEmpty())
        return;

    Set<List<String>> pluginsToCall = new LinkedHashSet<>(pluginOpts);
    //JavacProcessingEnvironment is created here
    JavacProcessingEnvironment pEnv = JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(context);
    //Since here, following will fail:
    //context.put(ParserFactory.parserFactoryKey, new MyParserFactory())
    ServiceLoader<Plugin> sl = pEnv.getServiceLoader(Plugin.class);
    for (Plugin plugin : sl) {
        for (List<String> p : pluginsToCall) {
            if (plugin.getName().equals(p.head)) {
                pluginsToCall.remove(p);
                try {
                    //My plugin is initialized here
                    plugin.init(this, p.tail.toArray(new String[p.tail.size()]));
                } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
                    throw new PropagatedException(ex);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I had an opportunity to add my plugin to `platformProvider`, it will solve my problem by earlier initialization of plugin.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to register my own parser factory? Or maybe the `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context` is not intended to use by plugin developers, but only by JDK developers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the least hacky way, as it seems that `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Context` functionality is intended for JDK developers (oh rly? I should have guess it when was adding 9 `--add-exports=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.*=mymodule` arguments)

```
    /*
    When I try to just put my factory here, I am getting
        AssertionError: duplicate context value
    but I can remove base factory by passing null
     */
    context.put(parserFactoryKey, (ParserFactory) null);
    MyParserFactory factory = new MyParserFactory(context);
    context.put(parserFactoryKey, factory);
    /*
    Now context contains my implementation of ParserFactory, but I
    also need to inject it into JavaCompiler which is the only object
    (FOR MY JDK: check your compiler behavior carefully with debugger)
    that have already got base factory with ParserFactory.instance()
    but didn't use it yet.
     */
    try {
        Field f = JavaCompiler.class.getDeclaredField("parserFactory");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(JavaCompiler.instance(context), factory);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```